# &nbsp; in Python 3.6 - getting text using an XPath expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, non-breaking-characters

```
<div class = "card-block cms>
<p>and then have a tea or coffee on the balcony of the cafeteria.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to check if the text I crawl of a website contains

```
texts = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='card-block cms']")
textInDivTag = texts.text
print(textInDivTag)
if u"\xa0" in textInDivTag:
    print("yes")
```

My output is as follows:

> and then have a tea or coffee on the balcony of the cafeteria.

As you can see, it doesn't recognize the non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character is recognized, but it is being converted to a normal space (`u"\x20"`).

According to the [comment in the Java Selenium sourcecode](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java#L145), `.text` / `.getText()` returns the visible text, and references the [W3C webdriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-element-text), section "11.3.5 Get Element Text" (emphasis added by me):

> The Get Element Text command intends to return an element’s text “as
> rendered”. An element’s rendered text is also used for locating a
> elements by their link text and partial link text.
>
> One of the major inputs to this specification was the open source
> Selenium project. This was in wide-spread use before this
> specification written, and so had set user expectations of how the Get
> Element Text command should work. **As such, the approach presented here
> is known to be flawed, but provides the best compatibility with
> existing users.**

So probably, this behavior is according to the specification, but I couldn't yet find the source code specifically replacing non-breaking spaces by regular whitespace. I could also not find an issue in the Selenium repository, but maybe you can give it a try by opening one.

Comment: thank you very much! I did not know that by using .text it &nbsp; get converted to normal spaces.
The goal was exactly this. I wanted to convert all &nbsp; to normal whitespaces so I guess that is not needed than, right? 
I can just use .text() and there are no &nbsp; in my string stored. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I replaced every normal space by `&nbsp;` and ran selenium again, and it gave me the same output as before.

Answer (score 1):

To match `u"\xa0"`, use

```
textInDivTag = texts.get_attribute('innerText')
```

To match `u"\x20"`, use

```
textInDivTag = texts.text
```

Answer (score 1):

### Non-breaking Space (`&nbsp;`)

A non-breaking space i.e. **`&nbsp;`** is a space that will not break into a new line. Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together (not break into a new line). This is handy when breaking the words might be disruptive. Examples:

- § 10
- 10 km/h
- 10 PM

Another common use of the non-breaking space is to prevent browsers from truncating spaces in HTML pages. If you write 10 spaces in your text, the browser will remove 9 of them. To add real spaces to your text, you can use the **`&nbsp;`** character entity.

---

### Element.innerHTML

- Syntax:

  ```
  const content = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = htmlString;
  ```
- Value: [**`Element.innerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Syntax) is a DOMString containing the HTML serialization of the element's descendants. Setting the value of innerHTML removes all of the element's descendants and replaces them with nodes constructed by parsing the HTML given in the string htmlString.
- **Note**: If a `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<noembed>` node has a child text node that includes the characters (`&`), (`<`), or (`>`), **innerHTML** returns these characters as the HTML entities **`&amp;`**, **`&lt;`** and **`&gt;`** respectively. Use Node.textContent to get a raw copy of these text nodes' contents.

---

### Node.innerText

[**`Node.innerText`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) is a property that represents the **rendered** text content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied to the clipboard.

---

### Node.textContent

[**`Node.textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.

- Syntax:

  ```
  var text = element.textContent;
  element.textContent = "this is some sample text";
  ```
- Description:
- `textContent` returns `null` if the node is a document, a DOCTYPE, or a notation. To grab all of the text and CDATA data for the whole document, one could use `document.documentElement.textContent`.
- If the node is a CDATA section, comment, processing instruction, or text node, `textContent` returns the text inside this node (the nodeValue).
- For other node types, textContent returns the concatenation of the textContent of every child node, excluding comments and processing instructions. This is an empty string if the node has no children.

---

### This usecase

As your usecase is to check if the website contains **`&nbsp;`** you have to use the **`textContent`** property as follows:

```
texts = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='card-block cms']")
for my_text in texts:
    textInDivTag = texts.textContent
    print(textInDivTag)
```